# DataContractJsonSerializer throws exception - Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dynamics-crm

I have a JSON string I want to deserialize to `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity` object:

```json
{
    "Id": "28bdb958-71fd-e711-8129-5065f38be461",
    "Name": "name",
    "Attributes": [
        { "Key": "key1", "Value": "value1" },
        { "Key": "key2", "Value": "value2" }
    ]
}
```

and when I have the following code to try to parse the JSON string above (let's name it `jsonString`):

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Entity));
using var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString));
var entity = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as Entity;
```

it throws the exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair`2 keyValuePair)
   at ReadAttributeCollectionFromJson(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonCollectionDataContract.ReadJsonValueCore(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonDataContract.ReadJsonValue(XmlReaderDelegator jsonReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
   at ReadEntityFromJson(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplexJson , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString[] )
```

The Dataverse NuGet package I installed is Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client, version 1.0.1.

Comment: Just FYI, I also filed this as bugs here:
- https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatform-DataverseServiceClient/issues/395
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/91104

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for my own question, but I still don't get why/how/what?!

The solution is to use lowercase `key` and `value` instead of uppercase?!

```json
{
    "Id": "28bdb958-71fd-e711-8129-5065f38be461",
    "Name": "name",
    "Attributes": [
        { "key": "key1", "value": "value1" },
        { "key": "key2", "value": "value2" }
    ]
}
```

Uppercase: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lm2gj7 - not working

Lowercase: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sbEJyl - working!

It took me a day to figure this out!

Comment: It is case-sensitive, and because it's deserializing a Dictionary object (`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`), it's expecting `key` \ `value`

Comment: @jasonscript: I understood, but why is lowercase `key` and `value`? I was expecting a uppercase `Key` and `Value` because the property of the key value pair in C# is in uppercase `Key` and `Value`?

Comment: You can see it in the error message: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)` the parameters `key` and `value` are lower case in the method